# Loading and Displaying Tiled Map Files in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, tiled

It's my first time working on a JavaFX project and I am trying to make a 2d game. I was experimenting around with Tiled to create the maps and such, but I couldn't figure out how to load the Tiled map files into the fx project. I searched around for quite a bit but I couldn't make anything work.

If anyone can help me with figuring out how to load Tiled maps I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: See: [eppleton/FXGameEngine](https://github.com/eppleton/FXGameEngine) and [Writing a Tile Engine in JavaFX](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/writing-a-tile-engine-in-javafx.html) (lots of annoying ads on that last site link).

Comment: From your second link, I've already added the JAXB lib's to my project, but I still can't seem to use the TileMapReader.